A commitment to amend and move forward
I posted ~1850 answers between March 2023 and April 2024, including ~1100 answers to bountied questions during their bounty periods. Of those 1850 answers, about two-thirds were based on generative AI content.
I would like to sincerely apologize for the series of answers I posted on Stack Overflow over the past 13 months, which were based on outputs generated from an AI tool (before being reworked, researched, and sourced).
I understand that this action was against Stack Overflow's community guidelines, which explicitly ban the use of generative AI for creating posts.
I do regret my posts, not only because they violated Stack Overflow's trust, but also because they potentially misled other users relying on the content I posted. My intentions were to contribute helpful information, but I realize I went about this in the wrong way.
I do acknowledge that I used AI tools to assist in creating content, which is clearly prohibited on the platform.
I accept full responsibility for my actions. All 1850 posts have been deleted.
I do understand the negative impact my actions could have had on the community. By using AI-generated content, I contributed to the dilution of the quality of answers on the platform, potentially affecting the trust and reliability that Stack Overflow works hard to maintain.
I will no longer be using any AI tools, and will only contribute by providing answers based solely on my own knowledge and expertise in future contributions.
So I apologize:

to the community I misled,
to the moderators (who are busy enough without my shenanigans),
to the Stack Overflow staff who expect better from me.


Huge kudos for accepting and owning what you did and being prepared to move past it

I appreciate the post, certainly, and was hoping to see it.  It's certainly been an "unusual" situation.  I'd add to the consequences that the community has been deprived of many answers that we know you were certainly capable of answering without AI assistance during that time. Looking forward to getting back to VonC-business-as-usual ;-)

You're a rather well-established user by nearly all metrics on the site, so I assume you understood the rule banning genAI content the entire time. I'm curious what the motivation was... did it seem like starting with genAI allowed you to write significantly more answers than you could otherwise? Or was it more about enjoying the fun of a novel ability (being able to generate somewhat usable programming content via a tool for the first time)?

Is there any difficulty to identify the one-third of answers that are not generated by AI tool? I trust your expertise and reputation so it would be great that if we can keep that one-third of your authentic, invaluable contribution.

~1730 posts were deleted**.

As someone who has been identifying AI here for a while now, I'm truly curious about a few technical details, if you don't mind my asking.  Some of the content was clearly from ChatGPT (the GPT4 model, at that, at least for a portion).  But were there any other generative AI tools involved?  At times, it almost seemed like you had a custom embedding or RAG based on Git information, but that could be purely my overactive imagination and was, in reality, based on your in-depth knowledge of that subject matter.

Fun fact: I mentioned that once before in the past, while I said "1 million reputation users", at the time I specifically meant you, but couldn't direct that, or that would be bad morals. Had felt it. No one is perfect. Not 1 rep, nor 1 million rep. We all do mistakes. Anyway, forget the past, aim for the future. Hope you can continue even better than before :-)

Can I make a really bold guess here. You signed up pretty much since the beginning when the site was still very different and more lax than what it is today. Far more fun to use, really. Were you perhaps using the site in a personal bubble and paying as little attention to all the outside noise as possible - which would lead you to completely miss out on all the AI hubbub that has been really impossible to miss otherwise? If so - I get it. I still pretend that it's the 90's from time to time, really good times. But there are limits.

Huh. This post is a bit odd. The tone feels rather like the compelled apology of a scandal-wracked celebrity, but that's a minor point; the bigger one is that you don't address why you did this in the first place. As @TylerH asks, what was the motive? Was it for rep, to play with a new toy, or to help people at larger scale? Do you actually think you were helping people (and that, regardless of the rules, it's a loss to the site that you got busted and the answers nuked)? What can the rest of us learn from this odd saga? You don't say, which leaves me unsure what purpose this post serves.

You haven't explained why you did it.

To clarify, did you decide to confess on your own, or were you caught?

Just out of curiosity: were the generated answers fact checked before posting them or just as is? If they were checked, for how long approximately? Also hard to believe that someone can post a thousand generated answers without anyone else noticing.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - Suspect a case of “this user has more reputation than the top .1% of the user base” bias was in effect, and nobody thought someone with a history of submitting quality answers, would ever intentionally break the rules so flagrantly.  Confused by the light punishment. A user who submitted a half dozen ChatGPT answers was suspended for a year. A user submitting hundreds or thousands of ChatGPT answers should not get the same punishment

@SecurityHound My understanding is that suspensions are typically based on repeat offenses.  After the strike, it was mentioned that a first offense would be a warning, followed by increasing times of suspension.  There may be other factors that sometimes come into play, but, if my understanding is correct, a first offense for AI/plagiarism would never result in a year suspension.

@NotTheDr01ds What happens after the 2/3 * 1850th strike?

@SecurityHound I would just like to get a bit more context, like for how long did people know about it or how exactly did the user choose the questions to "answer" and was it just a copy and paste action or more. One can probably only really understand this with more background information. To me it feels a bit like the communication from the company. You always have the feeling that you're missing some important parts. For example: Can we expect more apologies from other chatgpt users in the future?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution As a sort of "non-answer" to "how long did people know about it?", I can point to this post back shortly after the strike started as the first indication I should have had, but as you can see in that post, I thought that it simply must be a false positive.

Re: "Can we expect more apologies from other chatgpt users in the future?" Who knows?  I've seen a number of suspensions in user-profiles, and this is the first time I've ever seen a public apology from the user. Whether or not users choose to forgive or not, as mentioned by VonC, is a separate topic, but it is nice to see an apology in any form.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - I am not sure that information will be shared, nor do I think it is appropriate for it to be shared.  While I do not agree that a short suspension for submitting hundreds of ChatGPT-generated answers is enough punishment, the user was suspended when it was discovered they submitted ChatGPT answers in the past. I believe submitting a ChatGPT response as an answer is worse than plagiarism since, at least with plagiarism, you are copying a human's written work. However, in 2024, I suppose that's not guaranteed with AI-generated articles.

If everyone would apologize for everything the internet would simply fill up with these. I just want to understand the situation and if more context cannot be given, this is a bit difficult. I think the only thing that really needs to be done is for the wrongdoer to accept the penalty (probably done already) and double down in the future on making it up. Then everything is fine. And we can think about the rules. Maybe they need tweaking. Like how to better detect AI generated content, what duration of suspension is good, how to avoid that reputation also motivates negative behavior...

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Agreed! I think there should be special focus on defining what extent/amount of AIGC violations should result in what punishment(s) in a codified format. That is so that the users know what to expect from the moderators and the behavior against every (or most) AIGC violations is standardized. I am thinking of creating a meta post asking this so that the community may discuss and eventually reach a refined code of conduct against AIGC but I do struggle with eloquence. Would you, or any of the other users here volunteer to write this post in the light of this event?

Props for not disappearing and apologizing. I don't even agree with the AI rules here, but I value integrity tremendously

Honestly, it’s nice that you will move forward - but having thought about this, I don’t know how to move forward. This is a massive loss of trust into established community members that seems so far completely unheard of. It’s one thing that new actors don’t care, but this puts into question many of the foundations of the community and knowledge repository. (I might put this into a proper answer in case I find myself having any … left.)

The more I think about it the more I'm convinced that even this is AI generated

@TamásSengel Integrity? Where was that when he was posting over a thousand AI-generated/AI-assisted answers, knowingly breaking the rules? Apologizing after getting caught is not a display of integrity. Integrity is not knowingly breaking the rules on this scale (or any scale, for that matter), in the first place.

@SyedM.Sannan "Would you, or any of the other users here volunteer to write this post in the light of this event?" The bigger you make the scope of any discussion the lower the chances of getting anything done. It would be a lot of effort with little chances, I wouldn't want to spend this time now. The only question I would ask is if 1000 AI posts and 1 AI post really should be treated the same or if there is a difference and that difference should result in a higher suspension for the first case? My impression is that the mods and the community may differ on that one.

Terrible idea to delete everything. Lots of obviously valuable resources were totally torched. I'm glad you have warm feelings in your tummy now but think of others next time.

Not rhetorical: Before AI was available, how would we have handled a high-rep user being suddenly discovered to have 1k+ (out of ~30k) plagiarized answers? Would we have issued a short suspension and done our best to clean everything up? Should it be different for AI?

@Displayname VonC didn't delete them. SO moderators / staff did, as they were in clear violation of SO's rules...

@KarlKnechtel From what I've seen and done as a moderator, the handling of such a situation involving plagiarism on a similar scale would have been very similar. A notable amount of how we handle the moderation of AI-generated content is directly taken from what we developed for plagiarism. The mechanics of how to determine that something is plagiarized are different than AI generation, so it would have been different work, but how the actual moderation was handled would have been very similar.

In addition, if it had been plagiarism, it would probably have been an even larger task, as it would have been necessary to at least spot-check the entire date range of the user's contributions, rather than know that there's a limited period of time during which they likely would have been using AI generation. Note: While it's not the case here, it is possible to have used AI generation prior to the public release of ChatGPT. It's vastly more rare, but there was some AI-generated content posted prior to the release of ChatGPT.

The most boggling thing here for me is still the sheer amount of AI generated posts over an extended duration without any apparent detection or action in between. Reminds me of How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?, which never really received a robust answer. My take away would be that the detection rate may be lower than thought. I would have thought it to be 1:10 at least to really make a difference. But then it should have been impossible to amass so many generated posts.

I’m voting to close this question because "public apologies" aren't really questions. We do not need each user that gets suspended to come around posting an apology, no matter how sincere. If there are special circumstances about this situation that would benefit from community discussion; or about suspensions in general and how should the mods handle outliers such as this one; a question about that should be posted.

@yivi In my opinion this post is suited for MSO as this apology (or at least the action of posting these AI-generated answers which is also documented with this post) has some significance and there is actually Community discussion here (this should be obvious from the comments and answers). Also, it would be possible for VonC to answer questions the Community has (e.g. about his motivation) here (whether or not he plans to do so is their decision).

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The duration of VonC's posting AI-generated content (AIGC) was massively increased by all the things that happened around AIGC moderation over the period of time during which this took place. As is mentioned in the question above, VonC's posting of AI-generated content started relatively shortly prior to the company changing the AIGC policies and the moderation strike last year. It then was many months prior to moderators really getting back into handling AIGC issues/flags. We still have a huge backlog, just about 5,500 flagged posts, but we're working through it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Just posted it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430109/a-proposal-developing-a-standard-code-of-conduct-dealing-with-aigc

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Several people did detect AI symptoms in VonC's posts, but they tended to assume that they must be false positives, since it didn't make sense for a high profile expert with a huge amount of rep to use GenAI. But we should never underestimate the power of the Dark Side of The Force...

@PM2Ring So they decided not to flag these posts? With hindsight this was a mistake and they were unfortunately biased. Maybe high profile experts do seldomly use GenAI but if they use it, they do it in much larger quantities. Or users with huge amount of rep may be addicted to rep and therefore desperate to do anything to gain even more. In any case, the unbiased approach would be to randomly select posts and investigate them without any regard for who wrote them.

One interesting number would be how many AI/plagiarism flags were raised on posts of vonC over the last year and how many of them were declined compared to the average situation. Did people simply hesitate to flag high rep users or did they but the flags weren't followed up. That would probably help in determining what to improve.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution His posts were flagged. There is no excuse for this having taken that long.

@Cerbrus What about the size of the flag queue/time it takes for the average custom flag to be handled?

@NoDataDump Oh, they were sometimes flagged. They were even mentioned on MSE, although not by name. But those posts were also seen as evidence that AI tests & heuristics gave false positives, which actively hampered the whole process of effectively dealing with GenAI content.

@Cerbrus Investigating such a large number of posts takes time. Especially when they aren't simple ChatGPT dumps, but have been edited by someone who actually has a lot of technical expertise and good communication skills. Also, there's still a huge backlog of >5000 AI flags, some going back to the time of the strike action.

@PM2Ring Your comment reminded me of another situation which was much like this one, where a Minecraft speedrunner had gotten way with cheating for so long.

@dan1st the size of the flag queue wasn’t the problem, but I can’t really go to much into that.

If you can't go into that, can you go into why you claim there being "no excuse for this having taken that long"?

Not without throwing others under the bus, so I'd rather not, @dan1st.

@dan1st "What about the size of the flag queue/time it takes for the average custom flag to be handled?" If the processing speed of the queue is so long that a 1000 hits go unrecognized then there is only very small hope of ever catching a single instance of cheating alone. I would assume that at least one flag in this case should statistically have been handled and decided positively if handling and decision was sufficiently unbiased, even for very long queues. But maybe that was indeed the case and the problem is more somewhere else. That's why I ask. What should we do better in the future?

@VonC: I think that I speak for many in inviting you to address in comment, or as an edit to your original post, some of the more common, pertinent, and non-inflammatory issues that have been brought up in many of the comments and several  of the answers. Hearing more from you would be instructive to all of us.

This case makes me wonder if it's inevitable that we will lose the flight against AI generated content at some point in the future. On the other hand I also wonder how well these AI posts were received. If one takes, say the lower 1200 scores of all the 1850 last deleted posts of vonC, and compares to the previous 1200 non-deleted answer scores of the same user at a similar answer age or to random 1200 answers at a similar age, how would these scores differ. Did the AI (possibly with a bit of human help) produce high quality output or was it basically only commonplaces, no waste to be deleted?

Echoing what Hovercraft says, it does feel really weird that VonC does not respond at all in anything on this page.

@justhalf I think they haven't participated much on SO either except maybe responding to some comments where the responses link to this post so if they decided to not participate here for a while, I do think that's reasonable.

Hum, I first UV'ed, I liked the tone of the Post... Then 50 Comments, with many Qt's, and "OP didn't react once to answer any single Qt, so I retracted my UV. // I would myself have several Qt's: 1- Why did you use AI...? // -2 Did you answer in Areas outside of your normal Expertise(s)...? // 3- Did you test yourself the AI-aided Answers that you posted...? (Why nothing about that is mentioned in your Post...?) // 4- Last Qt maybe for Mods/Staff, if "only" 2/3 of 1850 Answers were AI-aided, why delete them all? OP seems genuine and it looks to me that 600 Answers didn't need to be deleted?

Hum, I suppose I have the Answer to my first Qt (about 1- Why did you use AI...?), with 1100 Qt's + Bounty out of 1850, that's a lot of focus on bountied-Qt's I would think, => Rep was very likely the culprit, even for some acclaimed User with >1M-Rep... // => Demonstrating the complete flaw/fail of the "gaming" system on 'SO' only based on Reputation and points... The more points, the better you are, of course...!

@chivracq While I am obviously not a mod here, I guess it's difficult to go through all of these questions and figure every question that isn't AI generated without any mistakes. So it's probably better to just delete all likely AI generated answers.

@chivracq "...that 600 Answers didn't need to be deleted?" And deleting them is a quite big punishment. 600 allegedly self-written answers (who really knows if it are that many) is a lot of work, I never wrote that many answers in my whole time here. But on the other hand, if there is no way to distinguish these 600 reliably from the other 1200 (and how could there be) you either delete all or none. And the mods decided for all because deleting none would mean that the AI content policy is history. Looks like they didn't have much choice there.

Yep @dan1st and #NoData, I understand, but as OP sounded "genuine" Mods/Staff could have "worked with OP" to outcast (= exclude from deletion) the 600 "real" Answers, maybe checking with another SME if OP only answered in their historical Area(s) of Expertise... Deleting 600 "real Answers" (= 1.5 Answers a day on 13 months, feels pretty comfy to me) is more a "punishment" for 'SO' and the Community, I would think, like accurately assessed in the Answer here by #MarkAmery, and of the 1250 "other" Answers, most were probably correct anyway...

... Feels pretty strange to me anyway that OP could go on for 13 months without being noticed, I know for myself, I see one Answer, ... that I think is AI/ChatGPT-generated, I already notice directly, => suspicion already, I check another 3-5-10 Answers around the same time/days/period by the same User, and I'm pretty convinced then if I was right concerning my suspicion on the first Answer... I wouldn't need 13 months to be sure...!, especially with sbd posting about 4 Answers a day on average... (1850/400) (All Posts I ever flagged as being ChatGPT-generated were all directly deleted...)

From what I have seen from this discussion (and possibly also others), it's probably not that easy and that moderators can (I guess) not provide details on why this is the case (and I do agree they probably shouldn't). However, I assume that the volume of other AI generated posts/other unprocessed flags was a significant contributing factor. Though my assumptions are wrong, there are people who have way more information than me on this topic.

@chivracq, remember that mods were effectively banned from removing AI-generated content for a while. That triggered a strike, which led to negotiation, which gave us a process to move forward with AIGC removal under certain conditions. Mods have been clear that the threshold is high. There's a big difference between noticing an AI post and removing it, especially when it's not a straight copy-paste from ChatGPT. Now consider the volume of answers to be reviewed, and the rate at which new ones were posted. While I'd have liked to see this handled sooner, I understand why it took so long.

@chivracq what do you seek with those questions? are you trying to find out how bad of a person OP is, and/or how much nepotism is going one here on SO? I'm not defending his behaviour, but seems this comment thread became a witch hunt. I'm also not satisfied with the contents of this post, but I think we can ask more constructive questions.

@Cristik, nothing about "Witch Hunt". not at all, I said I was rather supportive for OP.... don't know where your Qt/Reproach is coming from...!? // Only a bit sad to "find out" that OP "succumbed to greed", => more Rep, => always more Rep, + just like politicians => always more power, + and rich people, => always more money, ah-an...! // A bit "sad" or "worried" about the 600 or 1850 Qt's that are now "orphan" without an Answer, ... even if Rep-Farming usually doesn't rhymes very good with Curation (of the Site)... (Rep-Farmers prefer to answer Dupes than closing them, even if they know...!)

@chivracq the amount of discussion-based commentary happening here is getting extensive. please consider moving further commentary to a chatroom, or an answer post.

I can't say I'm very impressed with an apology after the fact, after apparently being caught.
While I can appreciate the transparency, I can't look past the fact that you should've known better than to do this in the first place. I mean, 1850 (now deleted) posts, of which about 1200 were (partially) AI-generated? That's a lot of flouting the rules, and consistently so over a long time span...
I've seen users get suspended for posting AI-generated content. Having your answers deleted isn't "punishment". That's just standard cleanup.
I mean, I really don't get comments like "You're proving once again that you're a great person." How does this make anyone a great person? It's abuse of the site on a significant scale, which got caught, resulting in an apology after the fact... That's damage control.
A "great person" wouldn't have flouted the rules to start with.
So, where am I going with this?

I'm not seeing any genuine remorse.
It's a political apology. "I've been bad", "I'm sorry I've been bad", immediately followed by an excuse: "My intentions were to contribute helpful information".

There's no reason provided as to why OP knowingly flouted the rules (on a significant scale).

The only apparent "punishment" has been the deletion of the answers.
That's just standard cleanup. Are we making an exception because OP's a high-rep, high-contributing user?

It took way too much effort to get a straight answer from anyone stating, "yes, he's been suspended for 7 days."
I get that suspension reasons are privacy-sensitive, but the fact that someone was suspended isn't.


Sorry, but I'm less than impressed.
You should have known better and you're getting off easily.

More than a week has passed since this "Apology" was posted, and OP still hasn't answered a single point raised by any of the answers or comments.
I get that this is not a nice position to be in, but it's one of his own making.
It feels like OP is just ignoring this problem now, or hiding from it, which makes me wonder why he posted this in the first place. The more he pretends the responses to his apology don't exist, the more disingenuous it looks, to me.

The only apparent "punishment" has been the deletion of the answers. — You aptly use the word "apparent" here to make it look like you aren't making assumptions, but then you immediately go on making the assumption that the user's rep/tenure played a role somewhere.

If someone committed a real crime and serviced their sentence, then I believe everyone deserves a second chance to get on with their lives. But this is can't be compared with an actual crime, it's just someone blatantly breaking an Internet site's rules in order to gain imaginary internet points. And besides, they have permanently lost all domain expert credibility now, so it's not like they can continue using the site meaningfully, at least not under that account. A lot of people get banned for like 1 year for CoC violations (and perhaps rightly so), so it does smell like double standards.

@blackgreen Your own answer suggests that he did get special treatment, in the form of a lot of people weighing in on the situation, (maybe even CMs?). That's not the same treatment a newly registered user gets after submitting a couple of LLM answers. Again, I'm writing from what I can see here. And it doesn't look great.

@Lundin as if his rep doesn't overshadow his "domain credibility" when answering ;-) I do agree with the "second chances", but that doesn't mean we have to accept the apology.

I said "multiple people", which really only means "more than one", and having more than one moderator looking into any issue which isn't absolutely clear-cut is nothing but standard procedure. It seems you, as a person not informed of the facts, are trying hard to imply that this user got special treatment because of his tenure on the site, when in my opinion, as a person informed of the facts, he most definitely didn't.

The main issue I have here is that disciplinary actions/punishments seem so arbitrary on this network. There doesn't seem to be any relation between the severity of the offense and the disciplinary actions, except for those who are repeatedly breaking rules. I often come across "1 rep" users and then you peek at their account and notice they've been suspended for 6 months to a year. I have of course no idea what offense that such users committed, but mass posting thousands of answers in blatant violation of the site rules seems pretty serious to me.

Then why be vague about it? The way you've written that answer almost looks as if a task force was set up to handle that situation. I mean, read this: "multiple people spent a great deal of time <cut (char limit)> while being fair at the same time." That comes across as a lot of effort that went into this. Again, I'm going by what I can see here and what's communicated here. What "us ordinary users can see" is that he got his >1000 answers deleted and a slap on the wrist, whilst he's being praised for "apologizing".

@Cerbrus Why be vague about it? Because the details of what happened is none of your business. Moderators don't comment about if and what moderation actions are taken against any user, in order to preserve their privacy. Therefore any consideration you make solely based on information that is public is doomed to be deficient and uninformed.

@Lundin usually there is no reason to deviate from the standard suspension progression. suspensions are really just a means to keep disruptive users off the site when there is evidence that they aren't going to reform (a typical example are cases of reiterated misbehavior). Moderators may occasionally impose suspensions with the primary intent of delivering a stronger message, however that's rather rare. Some of you folks seem to think that suspensions are meant as a punishment. They are not.

And you can't blame me for trying to puzzle together the pieces @blackgreen. "Why be vague about it" was directed to OP as much as it was to you. If he was suspended, why not just state so in the OP? (I still don't know if he was or not). "Suspensions are not a punishment"... Wat.

What's really bothering me, though, is that he's just being praised here. He abused the system on a massive scale. He got caught. His answers got deleted, but he retained a lot of rep. He wrote a political apology. There's nothing to praise here. His past activity and helpfulness are undisputable, but they're not relevant.

From what I understand the suspensions follow an increasing period of time, 1 day, 7 day, month and then more. And generally the purpose of the suspensions are geared more towards rectifying user behaviour rather than actually punishing the user. So punishment for other users would probably also have been similar as long as they reflected on their rule breaking.

@Cerbrus You aren't just piecing together the pieces of the puzzle — which, as I said, is simply wasted time because you can't, by design, obtain all the pieces unless someone breaks confidentiality. You are also making assumptions stemming from your incomplete puzzle. I'm cautioning you against making those assumptions.

So, us "normal users" might as well not contribute here, because we can't know all the pieces... Come on. Please don't be so negative, @blackgreen. Try to understand our perspective.

@Cerbrus, initially I thought it was a voluntary admission. This is the reason for   "You're proving once again that you're a great person."  :-)

To add some context (or a "missing piece") they were suspended for a week, there were 3 MSO posts and 1 MSE post that skirted around this suspension (Discussing a specific deleted answer and one directly asking about the suspension reason). This particular Meta post was posted just after the end of the suspension period.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah so clearly, posting any amount of AI content gives you one week of suspension are there is no severity grading here, the suspensions do not "stack". Either that or there are double standards. I'm certain that the moderator team can verify that no single user until now has ever been suspended for longer than 1 week for posting AI content, unless they were repeating the same offense once again.

@Lundin There are no double standards. You get longer suspension if you repeat the bad behavior. If someone has been suspended for more than a week for posting AI content, that means they ignored the message and suspension and continued with posting AI.

@DalijaPrasnikar And so the only possible conclusion is: it's ok to break the site rules, just don't get caught because then and only then, you have to stop.

The practical consequences of this is that this is a huge encouragement to all users who like to "gamify" the system, to mass spam plagiarism and AI generated content all over the site. Everyone is allowed to do that once, at any scale, until they get caught. If you are a new user with no rep, you have nothing to lose but everything to gain from that. And surely the new users won't get treated any harsher since there are no double standards.

@Lundin Where did I say that it is OK to break site rules? New users like old users have a lot to lose if they break them. New users can easily hit answer ban when their AI answers are deleted, and old users get a stain on their reputation (I don't mean virtual Internet points) they cannot easily remove.

@DalijaPrasnikar That is the consequence, since the suspension for posting 1850 AI generated posts is the same as the suspension for posting 1 AI generated post. The only difference is that some user who posted 1 such post and then stopped was caught early on. Whereas in the 1850 posts case, they kept breaking the rules over and over and over, despite the featured meta post which has been sitting on the main site for over a year. They were just not caught by a moderator. There are apparently no punishments handed out retroactively.

@DalijaPrasnikar It also wouldn't take 13 months and 1850 posts before a new (or low rep) user got suspended, surely. Without knowing how the moderation team works, I assume it also wouldn't take "multiple people spending a great deal of time" before punishing said user.

@PhobosFerro there are still plenty of users who posted AI and some are still posting it that have been caught a long time ago, but still haven't been handled since the last year's moderators strike. But they will be handled eventually, and their AI posts will be removed. So they may think all is good because they are going on for months with nothing happening, when actually that is very far from the truth.

@Cerbrus I 100% agree with you. OP was a role model and breaking rules for a period of more than a year is just not acceptable. Their apology is appreciated but, posting 1000+ banned posts I cannot comprehend.

I doubt it's cultural, seems like a perfectly normal interpretation to me (and there's some research to back that up as well: "An apology does not help at all after clearly intentionally committed offenses.".)

I guess this blogpost still stands, along with https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/287976

On the contrary, an apology is rarely worse for explaining why; even if everybody knows the reason is no good.

I don't know what there is to discuss here really, but I totally agree with the sentiment. I don't know what users typically get for posting AI-generated content, but besides rep lost due to answers being deleted (not that it could make much of a dent to +1.3M rep, mere pocket change by comparison) aside, we've seen users get slapped with much longer bans for less. This is just like when celebrities get off with some light community service and a well-scripted public apology. The praise just seems... bizarre, I just don't get it.

If I'm not mistaken, the tiered suspension ladder for AIGC starting so low traces back to the strike conclusions last year, as a compromise between SE and the community. That said, there's no point in suspending only for suspending. If one week is all it takes to turn a bad contributor into a good contributor, the goal has been reached.

@Cerbrus "Suspensions are not a punishment.. Wat" - suspensions are (supposed to be) a protection/rehabilitation measure, not punitive. If the site doesn't need to be protected from disruptive behaviour, and the user knows the behaviour is wrong, there isn't shouldn't be a need for (longer) suspension. Exactly how the ideal translates into practice is maybe a little shaky... but that's the idea.

Then why even suspend for a week? Then why ramp up suspensions at all? Regardless of intent, to every single suspended user out there, suspensions are punishments.

I think there's a misunderstanding in this comment section. I think Cerbrus is speaking of "punishment" more as a preventative measure, while it's being interpreted as wanting revenge.

@blackgreen "Some of you folks seem to think that suspensions are meant as a punishment. They are not." This caught my eye. I don't know what suspensions are meant as but I'm sure they are actually a form of punishment. Not being able to take part in this network is limiting the abilities of affected users. This artificial limitation effectively acts as a punishment. I can't interpret it any other way. And I think mods should be aware of that too.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It is not a punishment in a sense that we are not dealing with thieves and murderers where you want to give different and just prison sentence for vastly different crimes and severity. Some people seem to equate days of being suspended as a prison sentence and want that suspension to reflect number of AI posts. Suspensions don't serve as a justice system. While they are a kind of punishment for suspended person because they are not able to participate while being suspended, primary role is stopping and preventing further bad behavior.

And for the same reasons, it is not reasonable to hand out the same suspension to someone breaking the rules once as someone doing it 1850 times. The way punishments work IRL for real crimes is that the less serious the crime, the bigger deterrent effect there is in case risking punishment (and there's plenty of scientific evidence supporting this). And the other way around, if there is low risk and only mild punishment if you get caught, then the more tempting it will be to break the rules.

@Lundin You completely missed the point, and I don't know what to say to put you on the right track, because you keep insisting that suspensions are something they are not.

@Lundin standard escalation process is warning/7/30/365. Depending on the offence, user might get a warning or immediate suspension. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337396/  Not all guidance for moderators is publicly available.

@Lundin If you want a change in how suspensions are issued, you can always post a new proposal.

Suspensions are punishment to most users on the receiving end. It doesn't matter that they're not "meant" to be punishment. Saying suspensions aren't punishment is akin to a bully saying "It was just a joke". It's only a joke if both parties laugh. Even if you don't use it as punishment, even if you don't intend it to be punishment, IT IS perceived as such. Heck, ask anyone that's been suspended on SO.

@DalijaPrasnikar "While they are a kind of punishment for suspended person because they are not able to participate while being suspended, primary role is stopping and preventing further bad behavior." I get the general notion. Also in real crimes prevention is a big issue. Judging by the votings here my impression is that this apology and the mod reaction/handing out of a mild penalty is seen quite controversial by the community. Maybe people doubt that it's enough to stop the bad behavior.

Concerning rep retained status-completed

I accept full responsibility for my actions. All 1850 posts have been deleted.

Despite the post deletions, you have retained approximately between 15,000 to 21,000* in reputation from those posts in accordance to the default system logic for retaining reputation on deleted posts (post has score >3 and was deleted 60 days after creation).
To you, that may not sound like much. But that's 75 days of rep cap. That's enough to unlock the third highest level of reputation-based site privilege. Only 0.0735% of users have that much. It's no small amount.
Since you are committing to take responsibility for your actions, I would like to see you follow through by determinedly seeking for that reputation to be scrubbed as well.

*the number 15,000 obtained in the following way:

1355584 - 1193750 - (427*200) = 76434 (2024-04-23 minus rep on rep on 2023-03-01 minus rep in that period from daily rep cap)
1355584 - 1292783 - (7*200) = 61401 (rep on 2024-04-23 minus rep on 2024-05-03 after end of suspension minus rep in that period from daily rep cap)
76434 - 61401 = 15033

Cross checking with SEDE:

rep retained from bounties: ~13600
rep retained from accept,up,down votes: ~7988
13600 + 7988 = 21588



I do regret my posts, not only because they violated Stack Overflow's trust, but also because they potentially misled other users relying on the content I posted.

I'm personally surprised that a lengthy compromise of personal integrity isn't on this list. Regrets reflect an understanding of what was wrong. And indeed, you've shown that you have a general understanding of what negative effect this has had on others and on the platform, and have committed not to make this specific rule violation again. But I wonder about deeper lessons learnt...
Re: comments above
Some of the comments above (now deleted) think that these answers were simply to enhance existing subject-matter-expertise. You may want to take a look at this visualization of the variety of tags that VonC answers in over time (this SEDE query includes the posts that have been deleted):

For each month, it shows the sum of the following calculation over each unique tag for which VonC answered any question with that tag in that month: T_tag / T_total, where T_total is the sum over tags in that month of how many tags were in each question VonC answered in that month, and T_tag is the number of questions VonC answered in that month that had that tag. If all questions in a month only have one same tag, then the value for that month is one. More tag variation means higher number. Answering in a tag less than other tags also means higher number.

That's 30 bounties, of 500 each. Question is, what questions would be best fit for those bounties. I'd suggest let VonC choose himself.

The reputation can be deducted again by deleting the answers with the dedicated "plagiarism" flag or by dissociating the author from the posts.

Please, please, effing please with a cherry on top, stop caring about highscores. Even if you apply a x2 multiplyer and subtract 30k rep immediately, it would probably still display as 1.3m rep due to rounding, and rep has no practical effects after 5 digits anyways. I can understand if you think there should be more repercussions/punishment, but a very minor rep adjustment that's literally a rounding error is neither of those.

@l4mpi I disagree. "I can keep the fruits of breaking the rules- fruit which I was intentionally seeking" is not a good moral to the story here. VonC shouldn't be be allowed to keep a crapton of rep from breaking the rules just because they already have a lot of rep.

@l4mpi "Stop caring about highscores" Considering ~60% of those answers are on bountied questions, it does seem like rep was a major factor and should therefore be removed.

@l4mpi I mean if you think the rep adjustment is minor then it shouldn't really be a problem to forego it right? Reputation is probably one of the motivators behind this and removing that seems fair. In fact if they were to voluntarily do that or ask for it to be removed it would show more reflection than just an apology.

@super-starball-ultra as I said, I can understand if you say you want some sort of repercussion. But a rep adjustment of that scale is literally nothing. If you were proposing to reset his reputation back to 15k, I would like that proposal more than subtracting 15k.

@l4mpi a reset like that would be totally unfair and unjustified. you're not getting me. I'm not looking for punishment or "additional" repercussions. I'm looking for a fair result.

@super-starball-ultra "fair" is hard to even define in this context and impossible to execute. IMO a fair result would try to achieve an identical outcome to a parallel universe where the offending posts never happened. That would include removing the ill-gotten 15k, but it's the least important part - e.g. way less important than compensating users below 25k who were prevented from gaining rep and thus privileges (e.g. users who would have answered a question but didn't because VonC already answered), or than compensating people dealing with the fallout for their wasted time.

FWIW, the rep tab says -70878. You're around 9000 rep off, but I'm not sure why

We are already aware of the fact that reputation was retained on approximately 200 posts. We became aware of it about a day after the deletions were made. The time from then was spent waiting to see if the company had a way to easily remove the reputation, but, so far, that hasn't panned out. Moderators do have a way to remove the reputation, which is, as described above, to delete the posts as plagiarism (a multi-step process). We were, not surprisingly, already aware of that method. It is, and has been, our fallback solution, should the company not have/provide something more appropriate.

In other words, prior to you posting here, we were already aware of the situation that not all the reputation from the posts had been removed. We already had both a proposal/request to the company and a known-working backup plan. The company has been supportive, but, at this point, it's likely we'll go with the backup plan. If we go with the backup plan, then I expect a moderator will write some code to make the process easier, which is also already planned. So, basically, you seem to be upset about something that's already planed to happen, but just hasn't been accomplished yet.

@Makyen any plans to refund bounties to the users who started them at least ones which were awarded early in the bounty period? Looking at their earned bounties there seem to be 600+ answers that had bounties which are now deleted. There are probably some of these bounties which were awarded early on in the bounty period.

@AbdulAzizBarkat As far as I'm aware, that issue has not been looked at, nor has it been looked at in at least the vast majority of other cases where a bountied answer by other users has been removed (e.g., for plagiarism, AI-generated content, etc.).

@l4mpi "Please, please, effing please with a cherry on top, stop caring about highscores." Given the behavior being discussed in this thread, your request should probably be levied at VonC, not starball.

Hmm - your query that purportedly calculates "rep retained from accept,up,down votes"  includes the clause AND Q.AcceptedAnswerId = P.Id when selecting posts; isn't that excluding posts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266042/1709587 that are not accepted? Also, why do you have clauses excluding stuff tagged as Git-related?

eh, i don't see a problem with the original bounty posters not receiving a refund, the bounty still would have attracted traffic that all bounties do. The answer isn't what the bounty is paying for.

@KevinB me neither, but I was considering the bounties that were awarded early for example this one was only up for 2 days out of the possible 7 so they lost out on their bounty period which they otherwise wouldn't have if VonC hadn't posted that answer. There were more than 600 deleted answers where they were awarded a bounty, there's probably more cases where the bounty was awarded early.

@TylerH my request to VonC would not be that polite. But the request was directed towards anyone who cares about his rep number being different than it was before the fraud, even though it has literally no effect. IMO that's a waste of time and any energy directed towards that would be better spent on anything else, e.g. discussing if they should suffer any actual consequences besides the short suspension. But wasting more CM or Mod time on a BS number that does literally nothing seems worse than useless.

@l4mpi It is not BS, it is applying the rules equally every time. If you don't apply them here, then you lose the argument about applying them when a 100 rep user illegally gains 15,000 reputation too, and all other cases. Just because this case is of someone where the rep doesn't make a difference in terms of what they can do doesn't make a difference in terms of whether the rep should be removed. Otherwise a short suspension and a small rep tax is just "the cost of doing business" for rep fraud.

I'll add to that that cleanup of other related rep issues, e.g. refunding bounties for users whose rep does not have 7 digits and who may have lost privileges due to posting a bounty, seems vastly more important as well. And if that process also includes removing the rep from VonC, great, but if lots of time and/or effort would need to be invested just to lower his rep by 15k then I don't see the point.

@TylerH disagree entirely. A new user that gains that amount of rep also gains lots of privileges, which is the important part; and that should be resolved. The number itself does not matter in any other context, except for stroking one's ego. I'll add that a 100 rep user who gains 15k due to fraud should just be nuked IMO (and I wouldn't be too averse to applying the same rule here).

@l4mpi You are missing the point, which is that the rules need to be equal for all users. This isn't animal farm where high-rep users are "more equal" than low-rep users. And the rules being equal mean you remove all the fraudulent reputation, even if it doesn't impact the privileges the user has access to. That's called integrity, consistency, justice. etc.

@TylerH and you are completely missing my point, which is that removing this rep is nothing but window dressing in this case. The "more equal" stuff is IMO a fallacy; it's exactly because VonC is a high-rep user that a removal of 15k would do literally nothing but waste mod/CM time. Imagine if laws said there's a $1mil fine for assault but no jail time - that wouldn't have anything to do with "justice" even if you applied it to billionares and beggars equally. Want to talk about actual consequences for this behaviour? Fine, but removing a tiny fraction of rep is not it.

@l4mpi Sounds to me like you're instead expecting a different punishment, such as a longer suspension, due to the user having more rep than the avg AI abuser. Removal of rep gained and a 1 week suspension is fairly standard, and is applied to all users who abuse AI in this way. Why should the punishment be different in this case?

It's not like we're letting high rep users spend a miniscule amount of rep to avoid suspensions that would be a lot of rep to a low rep users... the rep lost in this case isn't in any way similar to a fine, it's a repayment of damages. There's certainly an argument to be made that due to the quantity of infractions a longer punishment may be warranted, but that too would be unrelated to the user's reputation.

@PM2Ring I was thinking of mentioning that too, but I couldn't find a strong enough logic/argument/plan for that route. Kevin already made the argument about bounties giving value of attention/views, and who would the bounty go to? to a random answer of the original bounty starter? (what if they have no answer posts?) to nobody, but started on the same question posts? to whichever VonC thinks is best? do we think it's good for VonC to be rewarding bounties to answers on the original questions? you could say that that wouldn't "repay" the choice of the original bounty starter of who to reward.

@super-starball It's probably infeasible for VonC to repay the people who gave him bounties over that period. But he could "pay it forward" by rewarding existing good answers. He has the skills to recognise those. ;)

@l4mpi "energy...would be better spent on anything else, e.g. discussing if they should suffer any actual consequences...wasting more CM or Mod time on a BS number that does literally nothing seems worse than useless." The number is BS, but a lot of users care about it regardless, and are willing to post bogus answers to get it. Our goal is to train them to stop that, and if giving reputation can train them to do it, if we were to, e.g., set VonC's reputation to 0, that could train them to not do it. Embarrassing that fellow humans can be trained like that, but might as well use it.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda "That's 30 bounties, of 500 each" - Hypothetically, it would be more useful and fair to put bounties on these very questions that now appear to be deprived of answers after answers posted by VonC were deleted (reminder, many of them were bounted). Not on some arbitrary questions.

Well, good for you, I guess.
Yet moving forward is not going to change that, quote, one of the oldest users on the platform by account age and — at the time of writing — the number #2 by all-time reputation, unquote, felt it justified that the rules don’t apply to them. That such a user felt it justified because, quote, [their] intentions were to contribute helpful information, unquote.
That’s exactly the motivation I hear regularly when closing posts, when voting, heck, even when editing or commenting constructively. Go away, we are helping here, we don’t care for your rules!
Sure, one could lie to oneself. Oh, those are new users, they don’t know better. And yada, Yoda, yada…
Now, this isn’t a how dare you post. This isn’t a how could you post.
Because honestly, it doesn’t matter who exactly overstepped the line. There’s another just around the corner, and maybe another right here and just not caught yet.
Maybe I would have met them on the next Q&A I curate. Maybe I will meet them on the next Q&A I rely on for help. But surely I can’t lie to myself anymore that they are not around, that they are not setting such an example. That they are not sabotaging, at a massive scale, why I rely on Stack Overflow for help.
If even people like you don’t give a jam about the rules either, why bother with them?
Apparently, people want that kind of Stack Overflow. Apparently, experts want that kind of Stack Overflow. Well, good for you, I guess. ⬇️

Rules matter. Policies matter. Quality matters. Some users do care.

Now, I am thinking about all those 7000+ questions that I have closed as duplicate that could have been answers. Too much Rep lost following the rules, sigh!

What happens to the 1850 questions that now have lost answers? This is a mess that still needs fixing.
A query that finds your deleted answers (plus others - I'm not sure how to narrow it down) reveals a bunch of highly upvoted ones (10k-only links to the top 5: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), all of them on questions that have lots of views and lack any other high-score answer. I imagine that in at least some cases, those were good answers and the questions have become far less useful to future readers as a consequence of their deletion. Were those answers AI-generated? Were they correct? What should we do to fix this situation, now?
This post is pretty frustrating. You apologise but don't explain why or to what extent you used AI to generate posts, why the mods decided to delete all your posts from the time period (even some valuable high-score ones that look to me like they're surely not AI-authored), what rules (if any) the mods have laid down to you about you revisiting those questions and answering them with manually written answers, or what guidelines there are about people farming your deleted answers as a source of inspiration for replacement answers of their own. Those are things I care about far more than your feelings of remorse, and would like to see addressed.
I think we can probably assume that:

the one third of answers that you wrote in the time period without AI were generally correct and valuable
some proportion of the AI-generated posts were also correct and valuable despite being AI-generated
in both cases, the presence of your answers will have tended to deter others from redundantly answering the same questions - meaning the questions from which your useful answers have been deleted will tend to now not have useful answers at all.

So we probably have somewhere from a few hundred to 1850 bricks fallen out of our library that we now need to repair. I ask both you, the mods, and the broader community: how do we do that?

Not to mention the bounties awarded to those answers that are now lost. Will the users stat started those bounties get refunded?

@Cerbrus A lot of bounties have been lost on AI answers in general, though that's across many, many users. We don't refund those, and I doubt we're going to start now, just because it's difficult to do. Plus, bounties going to waste is an assumed risk, which is part of why bounties are non-refundable.

@Zoe I get what you're saying, but this is a case of a user deliberately hunting bounties with AI... Oh, wait. That's far from unique. Well RIP that bounty rep.

@Cerbrus Exactly. Not sure what the current situation is, but right after CGPT became big, nearly every single bounty attracted at least one AI-generated answer, and usually several. Bounties are known honeypots for AI content - and unfortunately, it means this isn't a unique case. It's a large-scale single case, but across all LLM-posting users, 1100 lost bounties is likely a fraction of the total number of bounties thrown at AI answers. I don't have exact numbers in general, nor can I get those numbers without going through at least weeks worth of manual labour

"why the mods decided to delete all your posts from the time period" I don't understand this confusion, not all of the posts in that time period are deleted, this can be checked very easily by looking at their profile.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Some were undeleted after the fact, but they were blanket deleted

@Zoe I have a declined flag where I asked the moderators to review the answers deleted by the staff where it states "All answer deletions were confirmed with mods" so you're saying the moderators simply agreed to delete all the answers? No review involved?

@AbdulAzizBarkat They were mostly reviewed after being deleted and on-demand, because going through 1850 answers to check each of them for AI-generated content is an enormous amount of work

@Zoe so my flag decline message is false in the "all answer deletions" part? I'd have simply appreciated being left in the dark then rather than a lie like that (Not blaming you particularly) :(

@AbdulAzizBarkat Your flag decline message was not a lie. "All answers deletions were confirmed with mods" is true. We are not going to disclose full details of the operation. Nor why were some answers undeleted.

@DalijaPrasnikar Really? "all" answers' deletions were confirmed with the mods as the message says? Or is it like Zoe mentioned. Both are contradictory, for sure..

@DalijaPrasnikar so are you saying all 1850 answers were reviewed? Zoe's comment that said "They were mostly reviewed after being deleted and on-demand" wasn't really clear on that, I guess I misunderstood then. I really appreciate the work the moderators have put into this, I understand 1850 posts is quite a lot to review.

It seems fairly clear to me... they blanket deleted them all then reviewed and undeleted a number of them. There's no value in getting into specifics on how many were individually reviewed when it's fairly clear which groups of answers are more likely to have been not ai given the past activity of the user.

@KevinB Sure, but then the message "All answers' deletions were confirmed with the mods" is a bit misleading. It conveys that the mods individually reviewed every single one of the answers as Abdul Aziz perceived as well.

So what? call it misleading, it doesn't matter. you're never going to get a list of what was or wasn't reviewed and it's unrealistic to expect all 1850 to have been individually reviewed in such a short amount of time.

@tdy Which is why it's worth reviewing those, and it's likely those have been given many have been undeleted.

@SyedM.Sannan There is nothing contradictory in those statements. It is just how you are interpreting them. Again I am not going into details.

This is the part of this debacle that feels the ickiest to me; we've presumably lost valuable content that real curators deemed valuable in the meantime. I'm not sure I have anything of value to suggest as a solution, but that's the piece here that hits me the most... We've burned down a chunk of the library because it was tainted, and that's wildly unsatisfying, even though it was justified under the rules.

@zcoop98 Yeah, taking that into consideration, I really think there should be more consequences for VonC but then on the other side, I'd feel it'd be unfair to give him special punishment at the moment just due to the amount of content that is lost. I think there should be another SO post as a proposal to detail the extents of consequences for varying level of AIGC violations and see what the community says on that.

VonC could rewrite those answers manually, as a form of community service. Assuming that we can trust him to do that without cheating again...

eh, i wouldn't want a form of punishment/repentance to be answering questions outside of one's conform zone such that they felt the need to use AI to answer them in the first place. Better off letting those questions attract their own answers if they are worthy of answers.

@PM2Ring Part of the issue here is that at least the highest scored answers look to me like they were not AI-generated in the first place; certainly they can't have been purely authored by AI. They probably simply need undeleting; high-value non-AI answers to highly-viewed questions should not be getting nuked as part of this process. I really wish we had more information about what exactly had happened, because if VonC is now cooperating and knows which two thirds of his answers were AI-generated then it's nonobvious to me why we're nuking any of his other answers at all.

@Mark It's a messy situation. And it's hard to justify the amount of work that the community would need to do to clean up that mess. It's a lot of work just dealing with the day to day issues on SO caused by newbies who are mostly oblivious to how the site works and what our goals are. We don't expect senior high-rep members to add to that workload...

@zcoop98 we've presumably lost valuable content that real curators deemed valuable in the meantime - LLM's were trained on existing data, no information was lost by deleting those answers, what was lost was combining different sources of information into the same answer, and this kind of combinations is what generated the "AI hallucinations" phenomenon. Secondly, and more sad, upvotes these days are not a full guarantee of the value of the post...

@Cristik Again, the answers that were deleted were not all AI-generated and several of the highest-upvoted ones appear not to be, so even if I accepted your reasoning as it pertains to genuinely AI-generated answers, it would be largely besides the point. And even for the answers that did use AI, we have no idea of the specifics of how it was used, because nobody - neither the mods nor VonC - seems to be willing to tell us. If the substance of the answers was always provided by VonC, and AI was just used to tidy up the prose before posting, then nothing you say here would apply at all.

Oh..., yep, same essence and same analysis like I posted in a short Comment (max 500-char) here, +the next one. (Both Comments on the main Qt.)

I believe I can say, on behalf of the Moderation Team, that we accept your apologies.
It is refreshing — and hopefully inspiring for all users who have been or will be in a similar spot — to see that you decided to own up to your mistakes. Thank you for that.
Rest assured, it was not a decision taken lightly: quite the opposite. Without entering into details which might be best kept private, multiple people spent a great deal of time reviewing the situation as thoroughly as it was reasonably possible and making sure Community policy could be upheld while being fair at the same time.
You are one of the oldest users on the platform by account age and — at the time of writing — the number #2 by all-time reputation. We are certain you have abundant real-world expertise in your field, which you have generously contributed to our platform throughout the years. You do not need to resort to underhanded means to keep being the great contributor you have always been.
Welcome back.

I personally concur with this.

For what it's worth, we've handled other major users in similar fashion and sometimes we get ignored, sometimes we get anger, and we've even gotten open defiance. Once in a while you get a contrite private response at best. At the end of the day, suspensions are about getting the behavior stopped. But the best part of this post? It deflates an argument we get in private from others who say we're ignoring others doing it. Nobody is being ignored, we just can't talk about it. Having a public mea culpa we can point to is a boon to the moderation team in that regard.

I also fully agree with what is written here. I would have written something very similar.

I believe that all of the moderators keep the best interests of the community in mind; in particular I have come to hold @Machavity in high regard over the years, and seeing their comments here helps smooth ruffled feathers a bit. It would be a tragicomic understatement to say that I was disappointed to learn of this whole affair, but I don't know that there is any outcome that would have felt satisfying to me.

I assume you moderators deleted these 1850 posts, most of which contained valuable information, and 1850/3 = 616 of which were legitimate. By this, you did a disservice to the community. So just saying "we accept your apologies" is not enough. So, what of these 616 (and possibly more) posts — is anyone going to salvage them? Without any mention, I assume not, but it's important enough to mention explicitly.

@anatolyg The only person doing any disservice was the author who caused this mess (knowing well enough what will happen to those posts). The mods are doing their job, following established policy. Can't say I envy their position in a situation like this.

Just to make it clear: I don't intend to attack anyone. Please just regard what I write as facts and not an accusation or anything personal. Before deletion of legitimate posts, the site was better than after. I hope people can regard this as fact, without personal connotations, like we always try to do in this site. What I said (and I still want to say) is that we need more information about this. And possibly actions; I'd say we need actions but without any information, I can't say that for sure. This answer looks like a perfect place to put the information.

@anatolyg This was a bulk action. As a matter of course, we can't review that many posts. VonC did request some undeletions. We were able to get some community memebers to help us review that relatively smaller list and some were undeleted. But we don't have the time to comb each and every post made. If you find one and feel there's a case to be made that it was no AI generated, please mod flag it and we'll take it on a case-by-case basis.

@anatolyg While we re-look at posts if other people flag them, you should only flag such posts because you know that specific post is not AI generated. You should not flag such posts just because you "like" them, think they are "useful", or they have a high score/bounty, because those aren't what's at issue. Such flags should primarily (almost exclusively) be from the original author, as they are the only one who actually knows if AI generation was used on that post. [Unfortunately, authors still commonly lie about that, even in extremely obvious cases (not a comment about VonC).]

The moderator message that's sent to users in AI-generated content cases and for plagiarism explicitly tells the user that they are allowed to raise "in need of moderator intervention" to explain the issue on specific posts and ask for the post to be reevaluated. The text also explains how to find their "deleted questions" and "deleted answers" pages, so they can review their deleted posts. Users with >= 10k reputation also can use deleted:yes when searching for their own posts.

Disclaimer: I do not wish to accuse and hope this post is not interpreted as any form of speculating about what are private matters. In a healthy relationship, open dialog is essential.
Based on this unfortunate situation, do you (VonC) have any recommendations regarding the efficacy and hazards of the site's "reputation points" gamification on the site's objective: "To be an open repository of quality Q&A for the use of professionals and enthusiasts." [my paraphrase]
Recognized as "the #2 points holder" -- even feted when you achieved your magic 7 digit tally -- I believe most of us would benefit from hearing what possible role the attraction of increasing your points tally (particularly the alluded-to "bounty questions") might have played in clouding your judgement to play by the rules.
If the Garden of Eden tale can provide an allegory for "human nature", resisting temptation is not one of mankind's/womankind's strong suits. Each of us must objectively examine our own private past carefully before even considering picking up a stone to throw.
The "welcome back" reception some have taken the time to post speaks to how the community has come to value your contributions.
Granting your primary motivation was to add to the SO knowledge base, many responses here seem to imply a niggling thought that temptation of "the shiny brass ring" of becoming the leaderboard's #1 may have been a temptation too strong to resist. (Which of us is so upright as to say we would not be tempted, had we been in your position last year?)
As a "celebrate figure" in this corner of cyberspace, your ongoing silence about  (with apologies to Clint Eastwood) "A Fistful of Rep Points" and "A Few Rep Points More" creates a harmful vacuum; a vacuum that will only encourage ongoing and harmful speculations.
From your perspective, returning to the fold just a little bruised, please expound on your past and present thoughts about the benefits & hazards of the site's use of intangible reputation points.
In particular, looking toward the future, should the value of an SO question or an SO answer be solely assessed on its merits? Or should the published-everywhere reputation of the author influence the perceived value of a question or answer?
What would you say about "SO reputation points" at present, please? Granting that reputation points played no role in your motivation for 13 months, as a long time member of the community your acknowledgement of this aspect of the affair -- even the perception of this aspect -- may serve to improve the community in some way in the future.

I’m very pleased to see this post, and am happy to see the return of an extremely valued member of this community.  I hope that everyone involved, and participating on Meta, will continue to handle this with the same measure of grace displayed here. I also wish to thank the moderators for their patience, discretion, and compassion in the handling of this situation.
While we don't believe that an apology to us is necessary - responsiveness to community concerns is in our job, after all - we believe that your acceptance of responsibility is model behavior for the community as a whole.

Have you (and members of your team) had a chance to look at this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430344 (I originally brought this up back in April and it has been escalated through mod channels)? I am not expecting a public response, but the least you should do is posting something to Collectives SOfT and explain that you are not going to uphold the agreed upon criteria (see the screenshot in the link above) in general, or point out the reasoning for not doing so in this specific case.  Cheers.


By using AI-generated content, I contributed to the dilution of the quality of answers on the platform

This implication is incorrect: using AI-generated content doesn't necessarily contribute to the dilution of the quality of answers on the platform. As for your case, I subsampled 20 answers you wrote during that AI period and they look better than the average SO answer, so I'd also question whether that is even true in your case.
I'd also remark that this mass deletion caused several questions to be deleted by Roomba. I think it's unfair to the OPs, who aren't even notified of any deletion, and it's Internet unfriendly to break links for no good reasons.

I have not seen anecdotal evidence that roomba and link rot are "worse" with Q&A involving handled AIGC compared to the rest of platform.

So you have written two things:

(a) I did something wrong.
(a) I apologise for what I did wrong.

There are basically two reactions:

(b) Some people accept your apologies.
(b) Some people find your apologies insufficient.

So, this is what I expect from your side:

(a) I am willing to do things in order to pay back for the bad things I've done.

This is what I expect from other people:

(b) Set up a list of things he can do in order to pay back for the wrong things he did.
(b) Making sure that the list is feasible but sufficiently large.
(b) Any proposals, just for the sake of revenge-seeking, are to be disregarded.

Good luck.

3a: I'm not sure what he can do (himself). He can't strip his gained reputation from his account... All he can do is just not do it again, and I hope he holds to that promise.

@Cerbrus Or just positively contribute to the site like he was doing before the AIGC posting.

What a lack of commitment here. A person admits doing something wrong and apologises, I give him the opportunity to do more than just that and immediately I get more than ten downvotes. Guys, I've just done a constructive proposal. Is this the way you handle this???

Your proposal is no different from what is expected of every individual that has an account on StackOverflow, positive contribution. However, this expectation is in no way binding and lack of meeting it has no consequences for anyone.
The same applies here. We cannot set a list of things for VonC to do for the sake of amendment as it is not within our rights to do so. StackOverflow is an open community where everyone can contribute whenever they like to whatever extent they want in a non-binding manner as long as their contribution is within the rules of the platform.

@SyedM.Sannan: who says I'm only allowing him to perform actions on the public part of the website? Let's face it: the longer people contribute to this website, the more they get access. This person has a reputation of +1 million (!!!), so why not giving him access to the non-public part of the website and have him do some actions over there? Seen his remorse he might be very eager to do so and as a plus, he gets access to the hidden "secret chambers" of the StackOverflow community.

@Dominique There are no secret chambers... unless you are talking about becoming a diamond moderator. And for that, there are only two ways: They get hired by StackExchange Inc. as staff and in turn also get the diamond, or by getting elected. Both of them don't seem feasible as StackExchange Inc., the company, would be less interested in this as a whole, and the community won't like to elect them due to what they did. No one can just "give" them access like that. Also, that sounds more like rewarding for bad action, so not a good idea imho.

What is up with the odd "numbering" on the lists? With the latter two lists continuing the previous numbering and letters, but not actually being continuations content wise, this makes no sense to me.

I don’t think there are "things he can do in order to pay back for the wrong things he did". A high rep trusted user deliberately breaking the rules at a massive scale of both content and time just… breaks trust, not only in the offender that was caught. It’s long been a pain point that some people interpret the rules leniently, but this scale puts into question - at least for me - why one should even bother.

@MisterMiyagi: the odd numbering is based on the two roles in the conversation: (a) stands for the things, stated by the author and (b) stands for the things, stated by the rest of the audience. Better would be (a.1), (a.2), ... but I fear StackExchange does not cover such numbering style.

@MisterMiyagi: We seem to agree that the author has done something wrong and has apologised for it. The rest of the site could accept this or not (clearly you don't). My attitude consists of turning a bad thing into something good (I admit, this is a very difficult message to pass).

@Dominique I like your ideas in principle, but I'm not sure there's anything VonC can do to make it right. Unless this apology was a spontaneous confession rather than damage control after being caught (which seems unlikely based on what people have said), then the takeaway is that VonC cares about points more than accuracy, and therefore none of their future answers should be trusted either. (I'll also suspect that other >50k users might have similar motivations (honestly, I kind of already did)). The best thing VonC can do is leave the site so others don't accidentally trust their answers.

i don't really understand all the DV's on this Answer, I've actually UV'ed it... And I also agree with @Ray's analysis, => apology was a bit some damage control I think (mitigated by no response since 8 days = a bit of shame, I would think, not dare to check the Site), and motivation was a bit clearly Rep+Rep = More Rep...! // Give stg back to the Community, I have a great idea: Give the missing Rep-Pts to 50 ["selected" and proven] Users so they get 2k-Rep and can do Edits without wasting/spending 3 full days for editing a Post on 'SO' to improve its Quality...! :idea:

@chivracq I can't remember any selected and proven users on StackOverflow under 2K rep. Well, I mean, I do remember a few, but they usually spent their time in SOCVR and didn't do much on the site itself. You are either less than 2K reputation, or you are a recognized, frequent contributor.
