A proposal: Developing a standard code of conduct dealing with AI-generated content (AIGC)
In light of the recent events with VonC's AIGC violations and suspension, quite a few people have been discussing if a one week suspension (alongside content deletion) was sufficient or not. There were discussions surrounding if the suspension was sufficient, if it should've been longer, if there should've been other effects as a response to the violation, and more.
Considering the events of that post, this question is a proposal for the community (and practically, the moderators) to discuss and define a transparent, standard code of conduct when dealing with AIGC violations, that should be able to generate an answer based on a set of rules to the following frequently asked questions, among others:

Should the initial response to someone doing AIGC violations for extended periods of time and getting caught much later, say, in one year, be the same as someone who did their first violation and immediately got caught? So, if the procedure for posting an AI-generated answer once and immediately getting caught is 1 week suspension alongside the deletion of that particular answer, should it be the same for doing it for 1 year and only getting caught after posting, say, 200 answers? Should the timeframe during which the violations occurred be considered?

Should there be a creation of stages of responses to AIGC violation based on the amount of violations? E.g., if someone who wrote 50 AI-based answers should be treated the same as someone who wrote 2 or not.

Should the overall stature and reputation points of a user who did an AIGC violation be took into account when constructing a response to said violation?

Should people who admitted to posting AIGC at some point ignorantly be treated the same as people who were caught? E.g., should this user who once posted AIGC even before it being banned, and admits to what they did openly in a meta post, be given a suspension at all or just have their posts deleted?

Should there be a set of defined, documented severities in responses to AIGC violation based on,
a) The total amount of violations?
b) The timeframe throughout which the violations occurred?
c) The existence of previous violations?


The intent of this post is to define a transparent, agreed upon process for dealing with AIGC violations and reducing individual decision-making and exceptions as much as possible.

VonC’s transgression is especially egregious to me. If you have that much rep, you should understand community expectations much more than a 1, 100, or even a 1000 reputation user. Stylistically, I’m getting the impression VonC is  past the point of contributing organically and wants to maintain their reputation velocity. That mindset can make a user do things that would be against the spirit of contributing, if not the letter. I would have suspended them for longer, given the breadth and depth of their transgression. But, I am not a moderator. I don’t have to make those hard decisions.

define a transparent, agreed upon process for dealing with AIGC violations and reducing individual decision-making and exceptions as much as possible. This is moderator territory and for good reasons. Do not turn this into a crowed based  judging process. I also don't see any sign where there is "individual decision-making".  You don't know what transpired in private and from my observation this isn't a one mod party. Don't pretend moderators are acting on their own.

@rene I am not pretending they are acting on their own, when I said "individual decision-making" I meant decision-making based on every individual case, even if the mods do it as a group. Where the mods would have to judge the response to every single AIGC violation instead of applying something from a single source of truth. Imho, it would certainly save time for there to be one single text defining response to all AIGC violations and their extents, that is refined by public opinion so that the amount of cases where actual judgement is to be done are less and more time is saved.

@GeorgeStocker Well, that's another reason this question is for. So that moderators don't have to make those hard decisions on a case-by-case basis but rather have a standard text to follow for at least 80% of the cases. Where they can review the charecteristics of a specific violation and violator, and refer to the text to take action, and at some point, even have the actions in their reflexes. It is similar to the texts written on flagging, editing properly, etc.

There is a user who recently received a year suspension for submitting AI content on one community and received no suspension on SO, and content on the other community was discovered, due to them complaining here that everyone was calling them a lier for using AI. Inconsistent reaction isn’t good, no reaction to AI content, is probably the worse.

@SecurityHound Well, I don't think posting AIGC on another StackExchange site should result in you getting suspended on StackOverflow and only that site, but I think that is a discussion for another time. It still, however, proves the premise of my question that I further explained in detail in NotTheDroi1ds's answer's comments.

@SecurityHound If you want to discuss policies on other sites, then go to the meta for that site, or if it's a full-network policy, it needs to be discussed on MSE, not here on MSO. MSO is for Stack Overflow. Do note that policies regarding sanctions for policy violations are different between SE sites and things are adjudicated differently across SE sites. There are several hundred moderators across the SE sites, so things are going to be different. That doesn't even begin to get into the fact that SO sees more flags in a day than most sites have seen in their entire existence.

@SyedM.Sannan - In this case, they were complaining they were being told they had written on SO, when further research was done the user had generated AI content across the entire network. The only reason I am not linking to the user’s profile is because they are suspended in one community. I also have enough information to find their question here.

@SecurityHound Besides what Makyen mentioned, there are other reasons why something has been handled in particular way. You don't have complete information.

I'm a moderator on Super User and Pets, and used to moderate Meta SE and Software Recommendations, and my opinions here don't reflect SO policy. They'd be how I'd handle such issues on my sites though.
I think it’s worth considering the intent of the suspension system as designed, and I'd refer back to Jeff's old blog post. Suspensions were and are still not intended to be punitive, or to 'make an example of someone'; they're supposed to discourage bad behavior. To a lesser extent, we also use it as a way to temporarily disrupt something that seems suspicious or is going to take a lot of work to clean up.
The actually useful tool in such situations is a moderator message—the slap on the wrist aside, communicating with the user involved about what the infraction leading to the suspension, and coming to an understanding of what can be done better is the actual goal here.
In the case mentioned here - the user apologised, deleted the offending posts, and these things show the user is contrite about previous actions. As an experienced moderator elsewhere, that's an excellent outcome. I've been made aware the posts were not self deleted, and that would have been what I'd like to see simply due to the scale and amount of work needed.
Broadly looking at the issues raised in the question, and in view of the above


Should the initial response to someone doing AIGC violations for extended periods of time and getting caught much later, say, in one year, be the same as someone who did their first violation and immediately got caught? So, if the procedure for posting an A.I.-generated answer once and immediately getting caught is 1 week suspension alongside the deletion of that particular answer, should it be the same for doing it for 1 year and only getting caught after posting, say, 200 answers? Should the timeframe during which the violations occurred be considered?




Should there be a creation of stages of responses to AIGC violation based on the amount of violations? E.g., if someone who wrote 50 AI-based answers should be treated the same as someone who wrote 2 or not.


I'd say the problem is less the volume, and more the knowingly doing it for an extended time. That said, it’s worth considering if the potential longer suspension helps solve the problem behavior. Our goal here is to disrupt the problem behaviour first with the view of stopping it completely, rather than a per-infraction punishment. It’s not 'right' to do something wrong cause you didn't get caught, but that's not what we're dealing with directly.
Our goal here is to have the user post zero AIGC posts in future, rather than trying to select a suitable punishment for past infractions.
Longer suspensions to me are about sending a message as well as disrupting bad behaviour longer by keeping someone from being able to act upon those behaviours.


Should the overall stature and reputation points of a user who did an AIGC violation be took into account when constructing a response to said violation?


While I'll refrain from naming names, I've had to deal with a high reputation user breaking a fairly 'simple' rule. We're dealing with the behaviour as much as the person. The first suspension was still a week, then a month. As tempting as it is to go 'you should know better' - then we're in the situation where the rules are uneven. I'd go with a longer suspension if it was the sort of infraction that threatened other users (say being rude or abusive. Or better yet, replying to a suspension impolitely with 'I'll do it again), but still, my goal is communication, not punishment.


Should people who admitted to posting AIGC at some point ignorantly be treated the same as people who were caught? E.g., should this user who once posted AIGC even before it being banned, and admits to what they did openly in a meta post, be given a suspension at all or just have their posts deleted?


The user in question would have realised they made a mistake and taken steps on their own to mitigate the problems caused. I'd say self deleting whatever posts they could, flagging posts they couldn't, and letting a moderator know would be an excellent way to self correct. Especially during the period where there were no defined rules, or worse contradictory ones, I'd give some slack for that. I'd say this would literally be ideal behaviour when this does happen.
If the problem behavior self corrected, and the damage done is too, there's, to me, no need to suspend. Public apologies would also be optional to me.


Should there be a set of defined, documented severities in responses to AIGC violation based on,

a) The total amount of violations?
b) The timeframe throughout which the violations occurred?
c) The existence of previous violations?

I think the previous paragraphs cover A and B. C is an interesting one. Are the previous violations a sign of a previous pattern of abusive behavior?
Knowingly using GenAI/AIGC for posting does seem potentially something someone trying to crawl out of say a question ban, or engaged in voting fraud would do for example. I'd look at the user's overall suspension history and try to decide if this is a continuing pattern of problem behaviour, and follow the standard escalation, or if this is a different issue.
We'd certainly look at that though.
To sum up, I don't see a practical need to special case this sort of posting, and our goals of 'better behaviour not punishment' are not met by extra heavy suspensions based on 'just' volume and status.

"I've been made aware the posts were not self deleted, and that would have been what I'd like to see simply due to the scale and amount of work needed." Note that users in this situation would generally be unable to self-delete a large number of posts like this due to the rate limit on deleting one's own posts.

..... I mean, this isn't exactly a normal situation...

"Suspensions were and are still not intended to be punitive" - is there anything in the toolbox that is intended to be punitive? Or is there some philosophical reason for not "punishing" wrongdoers in this system?

Short version is we deal with behaviors not people, and negative reinforcement is generally a last resort

@KarlKnechtel I guess we should define first what is considered as "punitive" in a Q&A site... being not able to contribute, thus reducing the possibility of rep/badge gain? I can only think of that, since they still earn reps from upvotes on existing posts...


The intent of this post is to define a transparent, agreed upon process for dealing with AIGC violations and reducing individual decision-making and exceptions as much as possible.

It seems to me that this has already been made "transparent" as best as it can be.  From the Moderation strike: Results of negotiations:

Moderation should follow the standard escalation for suspensions, beginning with a warning and then escalating suspensions if infractions continue.

The problem, which isn't really a problem, is that we in the community don't necessarily have all of the details on any given user and the actions that led up to the suspension.
And that is as it should be.
Regardless of exactly what the rules are, either now or in the future, we have to rely on the Moderation team to enforce these fairly.
And that, as well, is as it should be.

+1 for the Regardless of exactly what the rules are, either now or in the future, we have to rely on the Moderation team to enforce these fairly., I agree with that entirely. The problem, which isn't really a problem, is that we in the community don't necessarily have all of the details on any given user and the actions that led up to the suspension. this bit, however, is irrelevant to the question as far as I can see.
The problem, in my eyes, is not that the process isn't transparent, but that a standard process and set of steps, or a text to deal with such cases doens't exist-

to begin with or it is at least not made public. I am not asking for details of every specific user to be made public, I now understand the reasons for them to be between the mods and the user until the user decides to speak themselves. What I am asking for is there to be a standard group of texts that is made to be cater AIGC violations and standardise the process so that pointless disagreements of if the treatment was fair or not, like in the case of VonC's question don't emerge further. Even if that set of text isn't enforced, it would be useful to have some recommended policies.

Once again, if this does happen, the moderators should be following and enforcing said texts and would largely be a part of constructing them.

Again, it seems to me that the process has already been laid out pretty clearly, from that quoted text.  If a user posts AI or any other plagiarism, they are warned.  If they do it again, they are suspended.  Again?  Suspended for longer.  I believe this is even laid out in some "suspension" Help doc, but I can't find it at the moment.  It's simple, it's straightforward, and it's completely transparent. It's clear, however, that you don't believe the current process is severe enough in some situations.

As someone heavily involved in AI here, I don't always like the results myself, but I at least understand that there's already a process in place.

Well, can you take a look at the sample FAQs I have seen and raised within my question and let me know if it answers them?

@SyedM.Sannan It does, pretty clearly - The answer is "no" to all of your proposed changes, because as you are aware, these are not part of the current policy.  Again, you are proposing a new policy, but you also seem to base that on the fact that you feel one doesn't exist today, or at least isn't transparent.  That, to me, is the core problem with your question.

Well, tbh, if you ask of my personal opinion regarding the current process, I am not sure of it at the moment. Even if you see the example of VonC's suspension, I go back and forth between "Well, it's one process for everyone regardless of rep" to "They should have seen further consequences based on their significance and reputation on the site", and both sides have their arguments. I can't reach one verdict regarding this, which is part of the reason I am asking for a policy to be made that deals with all AIGC on varying extents and severities and details with consequences of all sort.

Well, the thing is that the current process does not follow any specified policy regarding this besides what you stated. It doesn't answer the very basic FAQs I listed in my question that any standardized policy should imho.

It's just, "offenses will be met with a warning, repeating them twice with a suspension, repeating them thrice with a larger suspension.". There's no specification of how long the initial suspension is supposed to be for what level of infraction, is the initial suspension supposed to be the same regardless of the user doing 1 or 30 offenses but only getting caught on the 30th one, etc. That to me, is not a defined, transparent policy. it allows lots of wiggle room and calls for case-by-case judgments more than it is necessary, especially considering the [growing] magnittude of AIGC violations.

If such a policy or text is defined and enforced, or even recommended, moderators can handle AIGC violations on their fingertips and much swiftly, perhaps even understanding the right action to take immediately. There would be less of a need for a case-by-case judgment which would likely only be for edge cases with extremely specific details.

@SyedM.Sannan A suspension is meant to signal to the user that their behavior should stop. The default escalation is 7 days, 30 days, 365 days. A mod needs no judgement or recommendations for first time offenders: it is 7 days and can then follow the progressive line that is offered by default. You only think you make it easier for mods with your added process. It really is not. When a mod decides to overrule the default length they can and do that already without a defined and enforced thing for all other cases that warrant suspensions.

Standard escalation process is warning/7/30/365. Depending on the offence, user might get a warning or immediate suspension. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337396 Not all guidance for moderators is publicly available. Just because you don't know something that doesn't mean that there is no process.

@rene Your comment still does not answer the sample questions I have mentioned. Would a first, or for the sake of the argument, second-time offender get a 7 day warning for one AIGC post or 10 posts (Considering that they are caught on the tenth time), or are they going to get the punishment for all of the individual instances they did an AIGC post at once? This is one of the things such a policy can clear and prevent further questions from users.

@DalijaPrasnikar Well, If there is such guidance, then I am not sure if not making it publicly available has its cons. It simply clarifies the process more to people and prevents unnecessary questions.

@DalijaPrasnikar I just viewed the link you sent, really glad to learn about it it. But I still suggest that a more standard documentation be made for this that answers all of the most FAQs and handles a few edge cases as well. It makes sense to actually not enforce it, but a set of similar "recommended" procedures, that are also made public, should be made.

@SyedM.Sannan The main question is if suspension needs to be seen as a punishment. I  simply refuse to define it or even use it as such in my capacity as a moderator. It is a tool  to make impact on behavior, it is not a retaliation tool.

@rene Well, that is what punishment is supposed to be... actions that prevents bad behavior, punishments in good faith at least. Anyways, we have the same idea of it, I don't think it matters what exact term we use.

@SyedM.Sannan I don't think we have the same idea at all. Your question nor comments align with my ideas about moderation or how I want the elected SO mods to perform their task.

@rene Well, how are they different? I am only going to understand your perspective if you explain it to me.

@SyedM.Sannan The process for AI posts has been made public in the Meta post linked in this answer. " Moderation should follow the standard escalation for suspensions, beginning with a warning and then escalating suspensions if infractions continue." So the process is defined.

@DalijaPrasnikar Well, I believe I am not able to clarify what I mean as the "process" here despite multiple attempts and examples to do so, so let's just call it a day for now. Have a good day (or night).

I think that primary difference is that you keep saying that there should be a process in how AIGC is handled when you actually want different process than the existing one. "The intent of this post is to define a transparent, agreed upon process for dealing with AIGC violations and reducing individual decision-making and exceptions as much as possible." There already is an transparent (to the point it can be), agreed upon and documented process on handling AIGC posts.

It's really difficult to establish a general set of rules that somehow determine the appropriate length of a suspension (and yes, suspensions are a punishment, also if the goal is to correct behavior) for each case. Surely the moderators have implicitly such a ruleset internally if only to achieve some sort of consistency but they also have quite some leeway in how to apply it. They are exception handlers and so each case is slightly different. This specific case here is surely exceptional in its scope (and there should be more discussion especially on how to detect similar cases earlier in the future). There is not much sense in codifying suspensions and other actions extensively.
My impression is that the community wanted to tell the moderators in this specific case that the suspension is significantly too mild. The voting pattern and comments in the linked Q&A seem to suggest this. Maybe it's simply that parts of the community think that such a strong violation of the rule that forbids the usage of AI generators hints at a lot of determination and a short suspension will not be able to change that determination. Maybe there is some sort of feeling of proportionality at play. Personally, my impression is that the only realistic explanation is that an experienced user was addicted to gaining rep and therefore did everything, even illegal stuff, to gain more, a victim of the gamification in the end. If true, the best cure would be to take away the drug, i.e. no more rep. But that is probably too drastic a change to get through here. But I think it might really help.
Anyway, in such cases, if the moderators feel that the community has a strong diverging opinion, it may reconsider its actions and maybe consider a longer suspension to give the user time to really get away from the ingrained behavior. Community consensus is important, but one would also kind of need to establish it more thoroughly first.
This is just my summary of what I think that many other people here were thinking.

"suspensions are a punishment" - For the suspended user, definitely but for how they are used by moderators, probably not. One could consider the punishment a side effect.

@dan1st Suspensions are punishment and punishments punish. The proverbial stick in "the carrot and the stick". Behavioral change is the end, but the means is taking away something and that should be stated clearly. What you and others are saying (I think) is that justice is not the goal of the punishment and if the community would crave for for some sort of justice in this case the community would be wrong (or ill advised).
