Why was this answer flagged as plagiarism despite proper attribution?
Someone recently posted an answer to my question on Stack Overflow.
For those with less than 10K reputation, here is an image of the answer.
The answer included a quote from a GitHub issue, and I believe it followed all the necessary guidelines for quoting external sources. However, the answer was flagged as plagiarism. I am seeking clarification on what might have gone wrong and how to avoid such issues in the future.
Here are the elements the answer included, based on the guidance I found, including discussions on Meta like this one about quoting from GitHub:

Direct links to the source material.
Blockquotes for the quoted content.
A clear mention that the content was from another source, not the author's original work.

Could someone explain why this might still be considered plagiarism? What additional steps should one take to ensure the quotes are acceptable?

Maybe related, considering who posted the answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430072/a-commitment-to-amend-and-move-forward

@toolic oh understood. I guess this question is now a duplicate of that?

See specifically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430072/a-commitment-to-amend-and-move-forward?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment995568_430086

hmmmm so would this mean that the moderation team believes using AI is copyright infringment?

@graciano No. AI is banned for quality reasons. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1
