Accepted answer has disappeared
A few months ago, I asked a question which received a very good answer which I accepted.
Today, I went back to review the answer since I needed the information again.  However, the answer has disappeared.  I was under the impression that accepted answers could not be deleted.  Is there a way to retrieve the answer?

Answer was deleted by a moderator as being AI generated content.

Is there any way of seeing the answer again?  AI generated or not, it solved a HUGE problem for me.

Probably a collateral damage of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430072/a-commitment-to-amend-and-move-forward

Unlikely to be resurrected. It would set a poor precedent of permitting AI content regardless of how useful it might be.

It's a rather long answer. Is there some specific part you were interested in?

@DanielWalker Here is a full page screenshot of the answer: https://i.sstatic.net/IYbauEcW.png

"Is there any way of seeing the answer again?" - apparently... ask ChatGPT. But ChatGPT isn't actually intelligent, it hallucinates answers based on data it itself essentially Googled. So that would imply that the answer is out there still. Just not under your question.
